# Set height of UITableView which contain dynamic Cell Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have taken `UITableView` into `UIScrollView` now I want to set static height to `tabelview` and set `contentSize` to `ScrollView` because `UITableView` calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` every time when I scroll `tableview`.

I am setting `tableviewcell` size dynamically using below code.

Now question is: How and where i can set total height to `tableview` and content size to my `scrollview`?

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableDictionary *itemDataDic = [resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(275.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [[itemDataDic objectForKey:@"offer_title"] sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    if (labelSize.height > 30.00f)
    {
        totalHeight = totalHeight + 325;
        return 325;
    }
    else
    {
        totalHeight = totalHeight + 306;
        return 306;
    }
}
```

Comment: See cellforrowatIndexpath will call for each and every scroll of the tableview

Comment: i know but i want to assign total height of all cell to tableview and set content size to scrollview

Comment: just use numberofrows * cellheight for tableview height

Comment: i know but it work for static cell height i am assigning height dynamically to each cell see code which i wrote in question

Comment: I am thinking that even if you set full height of your tableView, it will still continue call cellForRowAtIndexPath every time. The call of cellForRowAtIndexPath will also be based on the visibility of tableView. So even if tableView has long height, so far cell is not displaying it will not call its cellForRowAtIndexPath. I am not sure, if provided info by me is correct or not, we need to write code and need to test.

Comment: you can do it by storing the height in dictionary with key = indexpath.row & value = height.. at the end add all the values..so when you try to add height for that key it will override previous one..

Comment: @iDeveloper setting totalHeight to tableview will not call cellForRowAtIndexPath .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'heightForRowAtIndexPath' is called many times for a cell, therefore,  totalHeight is calculated wrong in this way.

You need to calculate the height of your table on init and when the data has been changed.

```
-(void) reloadAndResizeTable
{
    CGFloat totalHeight = .0f;
    for (NSMutableDictionary* itemDataDic in resultArray) {
        UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(275.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize labelSize = [[itemDataDic objectForKey:@"offer_title"] sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        if (labelSize.height > 30.00f)
        {
            totalHeight = totalHeight + 325.0f;
            return 325;
        }
        else
        {
            totalHeight = totalHeight + 306.0f;
            return 306;
        }
    }
    CGRect frame = [yourTableView frame];
    [yourTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, totalHeight)];
    [yourTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i know this method but trough this i have to use for loop. i want any better solution if there is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, may be worst solution would be iterate through each rows and calculate total height of all the rows and then set those, like:

```
    CGFloat totalHeight = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.count; i++){
         totalHeight += [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i section:0]];
    //   add separator height as well if you have.
    }

// totalHeight is your tableview height.
```